# How to run unit tests with DSSS and GDC?

Tags: d, tango, dsss

I am very new to D and still battling trying to configure my toolchain.

I am running Ubuntu Karmic and would like to use DSSS with GDC and Tango or TangoBos.

Till now, I installed GDC from Ubuntu repositories, DSSS, Tango and TangoBos from [these repositories](http://codeblog.palos.ro/2008/04/06/ubuntu-dpackages-repository/) and I can compile using dsss + gdc + tangobos.

According to DSSS documentation, it should be possible to run the unit tests using

```
$ dsss build --test
```

but on my system, the --test argument is ignored. I have dsss last version (0.78) and its inline help does not include anything about unit tests.

Running ldc --unittest works fine (though I do not know exactly which libray it picks up).

Is there a way to run my unit tests using the same compiler & library than for compilation?

If so, is there a way to automate the testing or will I have to run it module per module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best I can tell, sometime around Karmic, Ubuntu's install of gdc started ignoring arguments such as "--foo".

Observe:

```
$ gdc --not-a-real-option
gdc: no input files
```

vs.

```
$ gdc -not-a-real-option
gdc: unrecognized option '-not-a-real-option'
gdc: no input files
```

So on Lucid dsss version 0.76, gdc (Ubuntu 1:1.046-4.3.4-3ubuntu1) 4.3.4,

```
dsss build -test
```

or

```
dsss build -unittest
```

should compile with unit tests

Comment: Thank you. 

I just installed the dsss binaries from DSource (http://svn.dsource.org/projects/dsss/downloads/0.78/) on lucid, having the same gdc version as yours, and now it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "dsss build -unittest".  I haven't tried it, but I see it being used with a little googling.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either. The --unittest is also ignored by gdc.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient, but it comes up prominently when searching on this issue.

I found that gdc works with the **-funittest** option, like this:

```
gdc -funittest -g -o unittest File1.d
./unittest
```

This will compile a single dlang file into an executable called unittest and then run the executable which will execute the unittest sections in the code and display any failed assertions.